# Can I solve this electric forces question by integrating velocity with respect to displacement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

In my physics tutorial for electricity, there was one question in particular that struck me as interesting. It is as follows:

> One particle has a mass of $3.00\times10^{-3}$ kg and a charge of $+8.00\,\mu$C. A second particle has a mass of $6.00\times10^{-3}$ kg and the same charge. The two particles are initially held in place and then released. The particles fly apart and when the separation between them is $0.100$ m, the speed of the $3.00\times10^{-3}$ kg particle is $125$ m/s.
>
> Determine the initial separation between the particles.

Of course, it is possible to solve this by first finding the velocity of the second particle (Newton's Third Law implies they have the same momentum) and then using that to find the total energy in the system but I was wondering if it was possible to solve this using calculus instead.

My initial guesses were to formulate an equation of the form $$\int^{0.1}_{x_i}vdr=125$$ or $$\int^{125}_{0}x dv = 0.1 - x_i$$ where $x_i$ stands for the initial separation but I am not sure how to proceed (or even if this is the right direction to approach it). I recall seeing someone having solved a question like this using some weird change of variables but alas I have been unable to find that question. Is it possible to even solve this via calculus?

Comment: I would think that a conservation of energy approach would be a bit more straight-forward.

Comment: Yeah it would definitely be but I'm just interested to see if there's a way of doing it via calculus :P

Comment: $125 m/s$ is the initial velocity of the particle right ?

Comment: No, both particles start off at rest but separated by the initial distance (which we are supposed to find). The repulsive forces that act between them accelerate the 0.003kg particle such that when the distance between both particles increases to 0.100m, the 0.003kg particle is moving at a speed of 125m/s.

Comment: Oh I understand it know. And when you reply to someone try to use @username so the people you wrote can be notified.

Comment: Do you know the answer ?

Comment: If we assume a is constant we can use $v_f^2=v_i^2+2ax$. If we not assume a is not constant its kind of tricky to use integrals. First we need to determine to write the newtons law. Then we have to write down the acceleration and then take the integrals. But the integrals will depend on the time but we dont have information about time. Maybe we can find the solution but it seems long to do.

Comment: @Reign The answer is 0.0141ms^-1. Ah. Is it not possible to solve without knowing time by a substitution for position somehow?

Comment: @Conrad Soon I think so. I find the x(t) but then i couldnt solve without knowing t. Using the Energy C. seems to be the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Reign Yeah. I tried mucking about again and I tried integrating a with respect to s. I thought I was onto something but it turned out to just be the kinetic energy equation in the end... Oh well.

Comment: @ConradSoon If we had more information maybe we could have find it.. Or as I said we have to take $F$ as a constant but thats not a good idea. So if someone can find the answer just by using the integrals with this info thats great.